# Convert a 2d double array to 2d double arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, 2d

I have a 2D Double array that is expanding and I am not sure of its final size therefore I want to convert it to a 2d arraylist but not sure how to do this I tried to define the array list first and use addAll(Array) method but it doesn't work. Any suggestion?

I just wrote this code I think it will work fine but I am looking for more efficient way

```
public class trial {    

 public static void main(String[] arg){

    double[][] Solutions_to_arrange={{1,5,2,8,4,70,50,80},{3,7,4,2,6,60,30,70},{8,1,6,4,2,10,40,60}};
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> Solutions_to_arrange_A=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>();
    for(int i=0;i<Solutions_to_arrange.length;i++){
        Solutions_to_arrange_A.add(new ArrayList<Double>());
        for(int j=0;j<Solutions_to_arrange[0].length;j++){
            Solutions_to_arrange_A.get(i).add(Solutions_to_arrange[i][j]);
        }
    }

    }
}
```

Also I have question on putting the statement

```
Solutions_to_arrange_A.add(new ArrayList<Double>());
```

Should I put it within the loop or its sufficient to call it just once outside the loop

Comment: Post your code and the errors you got please.

Comment: Is it expanding in both dimensions?  Do you want an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>`, or an `ArrayList<Double[]>`, or something else?

Comment: ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>

Comment: Your code with a double loop works (I tried it).  Unfortunately, since you've defined your array as `double[][]` and not `Double[][]`, there's really no way to do any better, that I know of.  If you make it `Double[][]`, you'll have to put a `.0` after every integer, since Java doesn't like converting an unboxed `int` to a boxed `Double` automatically.  But if you do both of these, you can write code with a _single_ loop using `arrays.asList`.  But this only works in one dimension, so you'd still need one loop.

Comment: (or you can put `D` after every integer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try it:

```
    Double[][] matriz = {{1d,5d,2d,8d,4d,70d,50d,80d},{3d,7d,4d,2d,6d,60d,30d,70d},{8d,1d,6d,4d,2d,10d,40d,60d}};

    List<List> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Double[] array : matriz){
        result.add( Arrays.asList(array) );
    }
```

If we use primitive types in "Arrays.asList" we will get a list with one primitive array as its unique item. With object type it will works fine.